# Is there a media type for time series charts?

Tags: mime-types, time-series, hypermedia

I was looking for a already defined Media Type on the [IANA](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml) to represent time series charts but I didn't find one.

Does anyone know of a media type, and if not, do you just use generic collection media types like [Collection+JSON](http://amundsen.com/media-types/collection/) or even [HAL](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html)?

Comment: I have been thinking about doing this for a while now.  It would be a really good idea.  I actually use this use-case as an example in our book and compare how it would be represented in different media types  http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001708/ch06.html#example_06_domainspecificformat

Answer (score 0):

I do think your best bet for now would be to go with HAL or Collection+JSON. If you are new to Hypermedia then I would start with HAL. It is the has the simpler implementation details but is still very flexible.

However, you are free to create your own media type and then get it registered. I looked through the types and could not find any for time series. I think there will be a need for a timeline based type. Perhaps something like Collection+JSON but every collection has a date time.